# How can I find the directory where Git was installed?

Tags: git, templates

I have written a suite of Git add-ons for use internally at work. It needs to install some Git hooks in the global template directory, but I'm having trouble programmatically locating the directory where Git is actually installed. I've found installations on our development servers in:

- `/usr/share/git-core`
- `/usr/local/share/git-core`
- `/usr/local/git/share/git-core`

Some servers, due to previous installs, have Git installed in more than one of these directories. I am looking for a way to find out the *real* template directory from which `git init` will copy the template files.

The `git init` code in question is in [`copy_templates()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/init-db.c#L114):

```
if (!template_dir)
    template_dir = getenv(TEMPLATE_DIR_ENVIRONMENT);
if (!template_dir)
    template_dir = init_db_template_dir;
if (!template_dir)
    template_dir = system_path(DEFAULT_GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR);
if (!template_dir[0])
    return;
```

However, this code is only run when it's actually about to copy the templates, so there doesn't seem to be a way to find out what `DEFAULT_GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` really is beforehand.

The best idea I have so far is to (pseudocode):

```
for each possible directory:
    create a random_filename
    create a file in the template directory with $random_filename
    `git init` a new temporary repository
    check for the existence of $random_filename in the new repo
    if it exists, we found the real template directory
```

This is still limited by having to construct the list of "possible" directories as above.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Madness. I implemented the above idea but on one server, the root user was running `/usr/bin/git` and everybody else was running `/usr/local/bin/git`, so it still got the wrong directory.

Comment: I know this is a silly answer, but is there harm in installing the template in every git install?

Comment: @Alan: Hmm. Of course there isn't. Good plan.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the above idea implemented in Python. This still has the problem of possibly finding the wrong `git` binary in `$PATH` (depending on who is running this), so it's better in my particular case to simply install the templates in all the template directories we can find (as mentioned by Alan in the comments above).

```
# This function attempts to find the global git-core directory from
# which git will copy template files during 'git init'. This is done
# empirically because git doesn't appear to offer a way to just ask
# for this directory. See:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228558/how-can-i-find-the-directory-where-git-was-installed
def find_git_core():
    PossibleGitCoreDirs = [
        "/usr/share/git-core",
        "/usr/git/share/git-core",
        "/usr/local/share/git-core",
        "/usr/local/git/share/git-core",
    ]
    possibles = [x for x in PossibleGitCoreDirs if os.path.exists(x)]
    if not possibles:
        return None
    if len(possibles) == 1:
        return possibles[0]
    tmp_repo = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        for path in possibles:
            tmp_file, tmp_name = tempfile.mkstemp(dir=os.path.join(path, "templates"))
            os.close(tmp_file)
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(["git", "init"], env={"GIT_DIR": tmp_repo})
                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(tmp_repo, os.path.basename(tmp_name))):
                    return path
            finally:
                os.unlink(tmp_name)
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(tmp_repo)
    return None
```